# How to know when React component is ready for interaction

Tags: reactjs, performance, web, lighthouse, web-vitals

Just curious what can be done to measure TTI (web vital) for a React app. As we are only interested for specific component TTI, so lighthouse won't be able to help here.

Answer (score 2):

Lighthouse's definition of Time to Interactive (TTI) isn't the ideal metric to use when trying to measure component interactivity for a few reasons:

- TTI is a lab metric where [First Input Delay](https://web.dev/fid/) (FID) is a better proxy to use for real world data, but at the page level
- TTI approximates when a page becomes idle by finding the first [5s "quiet" window](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/lighthouse/blob/949bbdb49c858e123c485b9aa222be9cae1e12ef/lighthouse-core/computed/metrics/interactive.js#L94-L100) of network (<=2 in-flight network requests) and CPU activity (no long tasks on the main thread). This approximation isn't the best approach to use when observing things at a component-level.

When trying to measure component-level performance in React, I would suggest either of the following:

- Use the official [React Developer Tools](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/react-developer-tools/fmkadmapgofadopljbjfkapdkoienihi?hl=en) to get a high-level overview of your entire application's performance sliced in different ways (component profiling, interactions, [scheduling](https://github.com/reactwg/react-18/discussions/76))
- Use the [Profiler API](https://reactjs.org/docs/profiler.html) to measure how long any component tree in your application takes to render. You can also use the [User Timing API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/User_Timing_API) in conjunction to [add marks and measures directly](https://twitter.com/brian_d_vaughn/status/1329184452778614785) in the `onRender` callback which will then automatically show in Chrome DevTool's Performance panel and in the [User Timings section](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sp1wT.png) in Lighthouse. This brings you full circle to being able to measure component interactivity directly in Lighthouse :)